# Save a large file using the Python requests library

Tags: python, file, http, python-requests, download

I know that fetching a url is as simple as `requests.get` and I can get at the raw response body and save it to a file, but for large files, is there a way to stream directly to a file? Like if I'm downloading a movie with it or something?

Comment: I do not think this is quite a duplicate. This is a more generic question and people are more likely to search for this question than others due to the wording, as evidenced by the answer's upvotes.

Comment: Even closed, the flag as a duplicate will direct readers to an answer.

Comment: Perhaps, but the approach is the same.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Oddly enough, requests doesn't have anything simple for this. You'll have to iterate over the response and write those chunks to a file:

```
response = requests.get('http://www.example.com/image.jpg', stream=True)

# Throw an error for bad status codes
response.raise_for_status()

with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
    for block in response.iter_content(1024):
        handle.write(block)
```

I usually just use `urllib.urlretrieve()`. It works, but if you need to use a session or some sort of authentication, the above code works as well.

Comment: That's a really good point.  Someone should point that out to Kenneth Reitz--or maybe submit a pull request to the project?

Comment: @jdotjdot: Something like `requests.get(...).save('file.txt')`?

Comment: Just a note--in the latest versions of requests, the prefetch arg has been changed to stream. So stream=True would be used here.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for explaining the correlation to urllib as well.

Comment: @Blender I'm thinking more like `requests.get(...).save_as('file.jpg')`--want to make it as obvious as possible what's going on, and "save as" is more associated with a possible change in filename.  Additionally, maybe a `stream=False` argument or something similar.

Comment: why the `if not block` check? could this simply be written as 

`map(handle.write, request.iter_content(1024))`?

Comment: @rikAtee: Because that'd create an intermediate list.

Comment: sure, `map` results in a list of the returned value of `handle.write`, but the function will be called for each item. As long as I don't assign the returned list to a name then we can ignore it. I'm still interested: why are we checking if block is falsey?

Comment: @rikAtee: Creating a list with possibly thousands of `None`s in it is wasteful. If you want it to be "short", use `deque`. As for the check, `request.iter_content` calls `.read(block_size)` on a file-like object, which returns an empty string when the EOF is reached.

Comment: @Blender thanks for the tip and info. how would collections.deque help in this respect? As far as I can tell it does not execute a function for a iterable?

Comment: @rikAtee: You'd do `deque(iterable, maxlen=0)` to "consume" an iterable, but I'm not sure where I was going with that when I said that it'd be useful.

Comment: This code is not checking for status code, but simply writes the server's response message to the file as a string, in case there was some problem. I'd recommend inserting a `if not request.ok: return False` after the `get` line

Comment: @Blender: also, you should also put it in a try-except block, as connection errors are throwing exceptions in requests.

Comment: @Blender @rikAtee I dug a bit into the code and am pretty confident that you don't have to check for a false'ish `block`: `requests.Response.iter_content()` [calls `stream()`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L657) on the `urllib3.Response` that is saved in `raw`. `stream()` is designed to [handle](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/response.py#L448) [EOF](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/response.py#L309).

Comment: @zsero Improving on the approach it might be more pythonic to [handle errors](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) through [exceptions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status).

Comment: I'd put lines 2-5 outside the `with` block... if the request didn't succeed there's no need to create the file

Comment: @Blender I get `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: `Response.save` doesn't exist. I was saying that it would be nice if it did.

Comment: @zsero You can also use `response.raise_for_status()` if you want to raise an exception when the response code is not within range of 200-206