# Basic http file downloading and saving to disk in python?

Tags: python, file, download, save

<sup>I've been going through the Q&A on this site, for an answer to my question. However, I'm a beginner and I find it difficult to understand some of the solutions. I need a very basic solution.</sup>

Could someone please explain a simple solution to 'Downloading a file through http' and 'Saving it to disk, in Windows', to me?

I'm not sure how to use shutil and os modules, either.

The file I want to download is under 500 MB and is an .gz archive file.If someone can explain how to extract the archive and utilise the files in it also, that would be great!

Here's a partial solution, that I wrote from various answers combined:

```
import requests
import os
import shutil

global dump

def download_file():
    global dump
    url = "http://randomsite.com/file.gz"
    file = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    dump = file.raw

def save_file():
    global dump
    location = os.path.abspath("D:\folder\file.gz")
    with open("file.gz", 'wb') as location:
        shutil.copyfileobj(dump, location)
    del dump
```

Could someone point out errors (beginner level) and explain any easier methods to do this?

Comment: note if you are downloading from pycharm note that who knows where the "current folder is"

Answer (score 228, accepted):

A clean way to download a file is:

```
import urllib

testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://randomsite.com/file.gz", "file.gz")
```

This downloads a file from a website and names it `file.gz`. This is one of my favorite solutions, from [Downloading a picture via urllib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python).

This example uses the `urllib` library, and it  will directly retrieve the file form a source.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But is there a way to get it working through requests?

Comment: Any possibility to save in /myfolder/file.gz ?

Comment: No better possibility than trying it yourself, maybe? :)
I could successfully do `testfile.retrieve("http://example.com/example.rpm", "/tmp/test.rpm")`.

Comment: @Dharmit Is there a way to close that file? I mean, I want to download a file, do something to it, then delete it. However, when I try to delete it with os.remove(path/file) I get error: no such file or directory

Comment: @ArashSaidi A little bit late to the party, but when you open it you could try using (in this case) testfile.close() to close te file before deleting, but when i tested i didn't get the same error

Comment: This is deprecated since Python 3.3, and the urllib.request.urlretrieve solution (see answer below) is the 'modern' way

Comment: What is the best way to add a username and password to this code? tks

Comment: am looking for the same on how to add username and password ?how to authenticate?

Comment: get this error: `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'URLopener'`

Comment: how do indicate which folder/path to save the contents of the url?

Comment: note if you are downloading from pycharm note that who knows where the "current folder is"

Answer (score 202):

For **Python3+** `URLopener` is deprecated.
And when used you will get error as below:

> url_opener = urllib.URLopener() AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no
>   attribute 'URLopener'

So, try:

```
import urllib.request 
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Comment: Weird... Why nobody votes for this answer when Python 2 became deprecated and only this solution should work properly...

Comment: Agreed! I was pulling my hair over the earlier solutions. Wish I could upvote 200 times!

Comment: how do indicate which folder/path to save the contents of the url?

Comment: note if you are downloading from pycharm note that who knows where the "current folder is"

Comment: You deserve more upvotes. I don't understand why solutions for Python 2 are still accepted.

Answer (score 120):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python/22776#22776):

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve ("http://randomsite.com/file.gz", "file.gz")
```

`EDIT:` If you still want to use requests, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114729/save-a-file-using-the-python-requests-library) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests).

Comment: urllib will work, however, many people seem to recommend the use of requests over urllib. Why's that?

Comment: `requests` is extremely helpful compared to `urllib` when working with a REST API. Unless, you are looking to do a lot more, this should be good.

Comment: Ok, now I've read the links you've provided for requests usage. I'm confused about how to declare the file path, for saving the download. How do I use os and shutil for this?

Comment: For Python3: `import urllib.request` `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)`

Comment: I am not able to extract the http status code with this if the download fails

Comment: urlretrieve is part of the legacy interface and the Python 3 docs state that it may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: doesn't work for me: `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve`

Comment: how do indicate which folder/path to save the contents of the url?

Comment: note if you are downloading from pycharm note that who knows where the "current folder is"

Answer (score 45):

Four methods using wget, urllib and request.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import profile as profile
import urllib
import wget


url = 'https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg'

def testRequest():
    image_name = 'test1.jpg'
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(image_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content():
            f.write(chunk)

def testRequest2():
    image_name = 'test2.jpg'
    r = requests.get(url)
    i = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
    i.save(image_name)

def testUrllib():
    image_name = 'test3.jpg'
    testfile = urllib.URLopener()
    testfile.retrieve(url, image_name)

def testwget():
    image_name = 'test4.jpg'
    wget.download(url, image_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile.run('testRequest()')
    profile.run('testRequest2()')
    profile.run('testUrllib()')
    profile.run('testwget()')
```

testRequest  - 4469882 function calls (4469842 primitive calls) in 20.236 seconds

testRequest2 - 8580 function calls (8574 primitive calls) in 0.072 seconds

testUrllib   - 3810 function calls (3775 primitive calls) in 0.036 seconds

testwget     - 3489 function calls in 0.020 seconds

Comment: How did you get the number of function calls?

Answer (score 38):

I use [wget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget).

Simple and good library if you want to example?

```
import wget

file_url = 'http://johndoe.com/download.zip'

file_name = wget.download(file_url)
```

wget module support python 2 and python 3 versions

Answer (score 6):

Exotic Windows Solution

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("powershell Invoke-WebRequest {} -OutFile {}".format(your_url, filename), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

For text files, you can use:

```
import requests

url = 'https://WEBSITE.com'
req = requests.get(url)
path = "C:\\YOUR\\FILE.html"

with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(req.content)
```

Comment: Don't you have to `req.iter_content()`? Or use the `req.raw` file object? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)

Comment: No, it just works, haven't you tried? @MichaelSchnerring

Answer (score 2):

I started down this path because ESXi's wget is not compiled with SSL and I wanted to download an OVA from a vendor's website directly onto the ESXi host which is on the other side of the world.

I had to disable the firewall(lazy)/enable https out by editing the rules(proper)

created the python script:

```
import ssl
import shutil
import tempfile
import urllib.request
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()

dlurl='https://somesite/path/whatever'
with urllib.request.urlopen(durl, context=context) as response:
    with open("file.ova", 'wb') as tmp_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, tmp_file)
```

ESXi libraries are kind of paired down but the open source weasel installer seemed to use urllib for https... so it inspired me to go down this path

Answer (score -6):

Another clean way to save the file is this:

```
import csv
import urllib

urllib.retrieve("your url goes here" , "output.csv")
```

Comment: This should probably be `urllib.urlretrieve` or `urllib.URLopener().retrieve`, unclear which you meant here.

Comment: Why do you import csv if you're just naming a file?