# Download and Save a file in python 2.7?

Tags: python, save, download

Coming from here:

[Basic http file downloading and saving to disk in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python?lq=1)

Is there any possibility to save the file in any folder? I tried this but i get error:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

```
import urllib

testfile=urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://randomsite.com/file.gz","/myfolder/file.gz")
```

Any possibility to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic http file downloading and saving to disk in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You're most likely getting that error because /myfolder doesn't exist. Try creating it first

```
import os
import os.path
import urllib

destination = "/path/to/folder"
if os.path.exists(destination) is False:
    os.mkdirs(destination)
# You can also use the convenience method urlretrieve if you're using urllib anyway
urllib.urlretrieve("http://randomsite.com/file.gz", os.path.join(destination, "file.gz"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The directory `/myfolder/file.gz` doesn't available in your server or pc. Make a real file path which exists in your pc or server. For example:

```
./file.gz
file.gz
```

This will save the file from where you are running your script. In other words, in the same location to your python script.