# How to download all album songs in a website

Tags: python, url, download, mp3

I am struggling how to download all albums in a website. Manually, I would click each album, which takes me to the album page and then click download. This is laborious.

Code:

```
import urllib.request 
tar_url = "https:songs-download"

data = urllib.request.Request(tar_url)
for line in data:
  print(line)
```

Present output:

```
TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate through data you'll need to use data.read() and then iterate through that like so:

```
for line in data.read():
print(line)
```

try taking a look at the docs for requests https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: I got following error `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'content`

Comment: After referring the link you suggested, I got the following working `import requests
data = requests.get(tar_url)
print(data.text)
for line in data.content:
  print(line)`   But don't know how to download?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: @Mainland downloading is another problem you will have to solve try collecting all links into a list and downloading them. This page should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954687/how-to-use-a-download-link-to-download-a-file-in-python