# How to download muliple files found in RegEx statement- Python

Tags: python, regex, download, urllib2, urllib

So I have a RegEx stament to download files from a website im scraping(personal prject of mine) and I would like to download the files found by the regex statements

**Question: How could i do this using urllib or urllib2?**

```
def GetImage():
    with open('TestPage.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            v = re.findall(r'\w+\.jpg|\w+\.bmp|\w+.\gif', line)
            if v:
                os.system("wget v") # Could I replace this with urllib.retrieve(v)?
                #Code to download files found in v should go here.
                print v

def main():
    url = "http://testpage/~drc/drx/index.html"
    webpage = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    content = webpage.read()
    f = open('TestPage.txt', 'w')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
```

I know that I can download one file from a specific URL, but downloading the images found in regex v is my problem

Comment: Why not use requests?

Comment: I wouldn't use regex to parse a url....

Comment: Im kind of set on using RegEx Statements - Sorry!

Comment: you first have to ensure that your matches are http addresses, but other than that, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python) may help. use a `for url in v:` loop to iterates through your matches

Comment: How do I ensure that they are http matches?