# download files from website with cloudflare using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, cloudflare, download

I am trying to download mp3 files, using python, from a website which has Cloud Flare. I know about 'cfscrape' module for python, but how do I use it to get download the file from the url.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read the help at https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is for downloading multiple files from a 'csv' file which has the links.

Note: I had help from here:  [Python download files by links stored in csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180791/python-download-files-by-links-stored-in-csv)

```py
import csv
import os
import sys

import cfscrape

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()

filename = 'nazm_urls.csv'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    try:
        for row in reader:
            if 'http' in row[0]:
                reverse = row[0][::-1]
                i = reverse.index('/')
                tmp = reverse[0:i]
                cfurl = scraper.get(row[0]).content
                if not os.path.exists("./"+tmp[::-1]):
                    with open(tmp[::-1], 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(cfurl)
                        f.close()
                else:
                    print("file: ", tmp[::-1], "already exists")
    except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it.

```
import cfscrape

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()

url = 'the website url'
cfurl = scraper.get(url).content
name = url.split('/')[-1]

with open(name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(cfurl)
```

Comment: This is for only getting one file