# How do I web scrape and download a file from a website with CloudFlare?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

So from the research I've done, it should be pretty simple to web scrape and download a file from a website. I'm using FlareSolverr to bypass CloudFlare, and hence have the following script to web scrape and download a file (the download link is the variable `link` in the following script):

```
def request_page(download_link, stream):
    url = "http://localhost:8191/v1"

    print(download_link)

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

    if stream:
        data = {
            "cmd": "request.get",
            "url": download_link,
            "stream": True,
            "maxTimeout": 60000
        }
    else:
        data = {
            "cmd": "request.get",
            "url": download_link,
            "maxTimeout": 60000
        }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    return response

r = request_page(link, False)

print(r.text)

#response = requests.get(download_link, headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print('Success')
else:
    print("Something went wrong")
    print(r.status_code)

final_url = r.url

print(final_url)

# Gets the filename (everything after the last trailing /)
filename = final_url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

# Sends a HTTP request to the specified URL and save the response from server in a response object called r
r = request_page(final_url, True)

# Checks if the request is successful
if r.status_code == 200:
    # Gets the Content-Length from the metadata from final_url
    filesize = int(r.headers['Content-Length']) / 1024 / 1024

    # Tell user we are downloading filesize
    print(f"Starting {filename}: {filesize} MB.")

    # Downloads the file to the directory the user enters
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

    # Tell user the current status and file information
    print(f"Completed {filename}: {filesize} MB.")
else:
    print("Failed to get the file.")
```

The variable `final_url` gives back "http://localhost:8191/", so it's not working properly.

I'm new to web scraping and am not really familiar with the theory behind it, so could someone tell me why this script doesn't work and `response = requests.get(download_link, headers=headers)` does (supposedly)?

FlareSolverr's github is: https://github.com/FlareSolverr/FlareSolverr

I used a code snippet on that github for a simple Python request, and did it twice because the first request didn't work, so I thought that maybe I had been requesting the wrong URL. I then requested twice, in attempt to get the final destination.

The response is a bunch of HTML. It seems as though it's just the HTML for a new tab being opened.

I also referred to the following StackOverflow discussion, using cfscrape. Unfortunately, this didn't work either: [download files from website with cloudflare using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948573/download-files-from-website-with-cloudflare-using-python)

Just in-case, the file is a .rar file.

Many thanks!