# Web Scripting/Rename/Download

Tags: python, scripting

I want to download files from web page and name the file with the link name. For example, there is a hyperlink named "Use Case", when I click and download it , its file name is "2015abc file" but I want its file name to be "Use Case EN". Can I do this by using scripting language such as python?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of scripting is easy with `urllib`. Also, you should search for similar questions before asking - there are already a lot of tickets asking about this [exact same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python).

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://website.com/index.html", filename="index.html")
```