# Download csv file through python (url)

Tags: python, urllib

I work on a project and I want to download a csv file from a url. I did some research on the site but none of the solutions presented worked for me.

The url offers you directly to download or open the file of the blow I do not know how to say a python to save the file (it would be nice if I could also rename it)

But when I open the url  with this code nothing happens.

```
import urllib
url='https://data.toulouse-metropole.fr/api/records/1.0/download/?dataset=dechets-menagers-et-assimiles-collectes'

testfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python

Comment: Yes! the answers is :
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://randomsite.com/file.gz", "file.gz")

but  i got errors:
'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'retrieve'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this. Change "folder" to a folder on your machine

```
import os
import requests

url='https://data.toulouse-metropole.fr/api/records/1.0/download/?dataset=dechets-menagers-et-assimiles-collectes'
response = requests.get(url)
with open(os.path.join("folder", "file"), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt an example from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib.request
url='https://data.toulouse-metropole.fr/api/records/1.0/download/?dataset=dechets-menagers-et-assimiles-collectes'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as testfile, open('dataset.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(testfile.read().decode())
```