# Read pptx file content from a url

Tags: python

I found this solution to read word file content from a url

```python
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

file = urlopen(url).read()
file = BytesIO(file)
document = ZipFile(file)
content = document.read('word/document.xml')
word_obj = BeautifulSoup(content.decode('utf-8'))
text_document = word_obj.findAll('w:t')
for t in text_document:
    print(t.text)
```

Anyone know a similar way to process pptx files? I have seen several solutions but to read the file directly, not from a url.

Comment: If you can read the .pptx file from disk, and not from a url, dowload the file then use that solution. [Basic http file downloading and saving to disk in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it can help you but with urllib you obtain the content of the pptx (variable `file`), use `cStringIO.StringIO(file)` in function that read a pptx file path to simulate a file.