# How to download a zip file from a URL with authentification?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to download a zip file from url @`https://tools.company.com/api/v1/prkit/download/10102665/` using below logic ,I dont see any errors but the file doesnt download either?any guidance on what is wrong and how to fix it?

```
import urllib2, base64
username = 'xxxx'
password = 'xxxx'
request = urllib2.Request("https://tools.company.com/api/v1/prkit/download/10102665/")
base64string = base64.standard_b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print result
```

UPDATE:

Tried [Basic http file downloading and saving to disk in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python) but it doesnt seem to have a way to authenticate,added a comment.Any other ways this can be done?

Comment: is there an example with authentication?

Comment: @TheoretiCAL - I already looked at that ,my code is exactly the same as the most voted one,I can try the accepted one aswell but am not posiitive..any other pointers?