# Fetching image via Requests in simple way

Tags: python, python-requests

I find `urllib` has [a handy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python) to get image from url:

```
urllib.urlretrieve( url, localName )
```

However [the `requests` way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114729/save-a-large-file-using-the-python-requests-library) seems to be a little tricky. Even the answer suggested `urllib` to do the job.

Is it correct that `requests` really can't do the thing just like `urllib` does?
Or, is there a `requests` interface similar to `urllib.urlretrieve()`?

My project currently using only `requests`. 
I don't want to import another tool for only one feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the response `content` of a response to a binary file, e.g.:

```
In [1]: import requests
In [2]: r = requests.get('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NwXieow8Dac/VfWsN9Gnc4I/AAAAAAAATB8/dbaO0RKfIhE/w426-h538/PP_%2B1944wm.jpg')
In [3]: with open('fred.jpg', 'wb') as outfile:
   ...:     outfile.write(r.content)
In [4]: exit()
```

Saves the image just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Note that urllib.urlretrieve() is useless with modern unreliable services. If the server answers with status code 500 (Internal Server Error), you have no ways to detect it: the function just writes down the server's answer (empty one or "500 Internal Server Error" or whatever).

With requests you have ability to check the status code.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a *GET* request, read the response and then save it to a file.

```
f=open("filename.jpeg","w")
data=requests.get("http://example.com/img.jpeg");
f.write(data.content)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

[The requests way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114729/save-a-large-file-using-the-python-requests-library) you are referring to, is solution which is suitable also for large files. As it was already pointed, small files, you can always download via `requst.get`:

```
import requests
with open("destination.jpg", "wb") as dst_file:
    dst_file.write(request.get("http://example.com/img.jpeg").content)
```

If you want solution that's suitable for large files using `requests`, it's not tricky at all.

Actually when you take a look at [urllib.retrieve code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/urllib/request.py#L234), you'll see that's under the hood it's doing basically the same operations as you would need to do for `requests.get` with `stream=True`, except (as pointed in @y0prst answer) it's not checking response status code, so it'll write into local file also content of error responses (HTTP 500 code).

You can define function like:

```
def requests_retrieve(url, filename, chunk_size=1024):
    with open(filename, "wb") as dst_file:
        resp = request.get(url, stream=True)
        resp.raise_for_status()
        for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size)
            dst_file.write(chunk)
```

And call it like `urllib.urlretrieve`

```
request_retrieve(url, localName)
```