# Why do some of the images downloaded with shutil and requests have grey bars?

Tags: python, python-requests, shutil

I am running a bot that periodically downloads an image from a website and uploads it to Twitter. Sometimes, however, the images get grey bars on the bottom, resulting in uploaded images that look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFd6x.jpg) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Iv6.jpg).

This is the code that downloads the image as 'localImage.jpg' and overwrites the previous image:

```
image_stream = requests.get('linkToImage', stream=True)
local_image = open('localImage.jpg', 'wb')
image_stream.decode_content = True
shutil.copyfileobj(image_stream.raw, local_image)
```

The entire repository is [here](https://github.com/danlenshin/Art-Every-Hour-Twitter-Bot).

My question is what is it that could be causing the image to upload with the grey boxes on the bottom?

Comment: I don't know exactly what the problem is, seems like not writing the last chunk of image info. Try out this answer, might just solve your problems without having to debug further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14114741/1609219

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't exactly what I needed but it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't figure out exactly why the grey boxes were appearing over the images, I did find a solution in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests).

```
image_stream = requests.get(extracted[2], stream=True)
with  open('localImage.jpg', 'wb') as image:
    for chunk in image_stream:
        image.write(chunk)
```

Instead of using shutil's `copyfileobj` method, I used the `.write` method to write chunks of the stream to the local image. This seems to have solved the problem of the grey boxes.