# Regex to read tags Python

Tags: python, html, regex, tags

I want to read elements within tags with regex, example:

```
<td>Stuff Here</td>
<td>stuff 
</td>
```

I am using the following: `re.findall(re.compile('<td>(.*)</td>'), str(line).strip())`

How come I can read the first `<td>` tag, but not the second?

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/770830) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I assume that `line` contains the entire HTML document, and not just a single line as its name would imply.

One issue is that by default, `.` doesn't match the newline:

```
In [3]: re.findall('.', '\n')
Out[3]: []
```

You either need to remove embedded newlines (which `strip()` doesn't do BTW), or use `re.DOTALL`:

```
In [4]: re.findall('.', '\n', re.DOTALL)
Out[4]: ['\n']
```

Also, you should change the `.*` to `.*?` to make the expression non-greedy.

Another, bigger, issue is that a regex-based approach is insufficiently general to parse arbitrary HTML. See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for a nice discussion.

Comment: my `line` stores the `<td>[...]</td>`, its used in a `for` loop

Comment: Actually I changed my answer to this: `cell =  line.find('td', text = True)`

Answer (score 5):

For the general case, you [can't use regular expressions for parsing markup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/201359). The best you can do is to start using an HTML parser, there are many [good options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python) out there, IMHO [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a good choice.

Comment: Modern versions of Beautiful Soup have switched to using `lxml.html` on the backend. Why not use that directly?