# findAll function BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to parse text elements stored in between `<td>` tags, for example:

```
<tr>
<td>Trading Hours</td>
<td><b>Monday</b> <br />
London - 23:00 Sunday - 23:00 Monday<br />
New York - 18:00 Sunday - 18:00 Monday<br />
Chicago - 17:00 Sunday - 17:00 Monday<br />
<br />
<b>Tuesday-Friday</b> <br />
London - 01:00 - 23:00<br />
New York - 20:00 - 18:00<br />
Chicago - 19:00 - 17:00<br />
</td>
</tr>
```

In this simple example, there only 2 `<td>` tags and suppose a variable `tr` stores entire block of html code. My logic for extracting text is as follow (without any `<tr>` or `<br>` tags):

```
for td in tr.findAll('td'):
    row.append((td.find('td', text = True)).strip().strip('\n'))
```

Problem: My `for` loop recognizes the first `<td>` tag, but not the second. How can I improve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python). Clarify if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text=True` tells BeautifulSoup to look for elements with text. If you want to get the text, you need to use `.get_text()`:

```
td.find('td', text=True).get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: Even before getting the texts, when I do: `for td in tr.findAll('td'): print td`, it'll only print the first `<td> ... </td>` tag and not the second. I was trying to figure out why that happens.

Comment: @MaxKim: Where are you getting this HTML? It's probably malformed.

Comment: @MaxKim, what version of BeautifulSoup are you using? I used the same html that you posted and it found both td's elements. The html you posted looks well formed to me.

Comment: I'm using Beautifulsoup 3, I get an error with `.get_text()`: `'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'`