# Python Regular Expression Webpage

Tags: python, html, regex

I need help writing a regular expression for a webpage to extract some data. The webpage is:
http://www.city-data.com/city/Addison-Texas.html

I want to return "Dallas" from this bit of html code:

```
<a href="/county/Dallas_County-TX.html">Dallas County</a>
</p>
<b>Population in 2012:</b>
```

This is the regular expression I have written so far, but it does not seem to work. Any idea what I did wrong?

```
(">(.)/sCounty</a>\n</p>\n<b>Population in 2012:</b>")
```

Comment: Space isn't `/s` but `\s`.

Comment: I still receive the same error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Take one of the solutions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11709079/18771). You don't want to use regular expressions on HTML, *because regular expressions are unable to parse HTML*.

Comment: The secret is to never use regex to parse html. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: `(.)` matches a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the other way around of solving it, rather than using `regex` is using `split` function.

```
s.split('</a>')[0].split('>')[1].split(' ')[0]
```

should return the answer you intended.

However, using the above method becomes tedious for more complex HTML. you can use [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser) module instead.

Comment: +1 The only right answer when someone asks for an html regex is to tell them to stop using regex for html.