# building an outline from a webpage,python

Tags: python, html

i am trying to create a function that is to open the URL and construct an outline from the HTML code.The outline should include text between any ...tags.basically just to create an outline from a specific web page.Each heading level should also be properly numbered, with heading hx having x levels of numbering. How to start?

Comment: It would be more clear if you can give an example of an html and corresponding output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python

Comment: @user2963623 basically i am creating an outline from this http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~lillis/016/2014Summer/assignments/HW12/jazz.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tags in the `html` you have linked, besides `headings`. Anyway this is to get you started:

You need the packages `beautifulsoup4` and requests for `this`. Python comes with inbuilt packages for these oprations, however the above 2 packages make the job extremely easy.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~lillis/016/2014Summer/assignments/HW12/jazz.html").text
#If you want to parse another url, change the link within get()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print soup.body
```

This will print all the `tags`, `texts` and other contents within the `body` tag of the `html`. If you want a different output or something more specific put a comment below. I'll change the code.

Comment: is there another way of constructing the outline using <hx> and </hx> tags?

Comment: So you only want the heading tags?

Comment: yes only the headings. and when you read the lines for the headings, are they sting or list?