# How to use re module in python to extract information?

Tags: python, html, regex

I write a little script to use collins website for translation. heres my code:

```
import urllib.request
import re
def translate(search):
    base_url = 'http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/'
    url = base_url + search
    p = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    f = open('t.txt', 'w+b')
    f.write(p)
    f.close()
    f = open('t.txt', 'r')
    t = f.read()
    m = re.search(r'(<span class="def">)(\w.*)(</span>]*)',t)
    n = m.group(2)
    print(n)
    f.close()
```

I have some questions:

1. I can't use re.search on p. it raises this error: 
   `TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`
   is there a way to use `re.search` without saving it?
2. After saving file I should reopen it to use re.search otherwise it raises this error: `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` why this error happens?
3. in this program I want to extract information between `<span class="def"> and </span>` from first match. but pattern that I wrote not work good in all cases. for example translate('three') is good. out put is : "totaling one more than two" but for translate('tree') out put is:
   "a treelike bush or shrub   â‡’ a rose tree"
   is there a way to correct this pattern. regular expression or any other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `read` on the response returned by `urllib`, you get a `bytes` object, which you need to decode to convert it to a string.

Change

```
    p=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

to

```
    p=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```

You should read this https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html to understand why because issues like this come up a lot.

Also, [you probably don't want to parse HTML using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Some better alternatives for Python are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python).