# robust DOM parsing with getElementsByTagName

Tags: python, dom

The following (from "Dive into Python")

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('/path/to/index.html')
reflist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('img')
```

failed with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/htmlToNumEmbedded.py", line 2, in <module>
    xmldoc = minidom.parse('/path/to/index.html')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 924, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 12, column 4
```

Using `lxml`, which is recommended by http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2008/12/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library.html, allows you to parse the document, but it does not seem to have an `getElementsByTagName`. The following works:

```
from lxml import html
xmldoc = html.parse('/path/to/index.html')
root = xmldoc.getroot()
for i in root.iter("img"):
    print i
```

but seems kludgey: is there a built-in function that I overlooked?

Or another more elegant way to have **robust DOM parsing with getElementsByTagName**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of Element, instead of iterating the return value of the `Element.iter`, call `list` on it:

```
from lxml import html
reflist = list(html.parse('/path/to/index.html.html').iter('img'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup for this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('/path/to/index.html') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
soup.find_all("img")
```

See [Going through HTML DOM in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001307/going-through-html-dom-in-python)