# extract contact information from html with python

Tags: python, extract

Here is a sample html

```
<div class="yui3-u-5-6" id="browse-products">
<div id="kazbah-contact">
  <span class="contact-info-title">Contact 00Nothing:</span>
  <a href="mailto:info@00nothing.com">info@00nothing.com</a> | 800-410-2074
   | C/O Score X Score
    &nbsp;8118-D Statesville Rd
    ,
  Charlotte,
  NC
  28269
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

I want to extract the contact information here, email, phone, and address.
How should I do that with python? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I read that. But How I can get the information after "|"? I mean, get info@00nothing.com is easy, but it's hard to get phone and address

Comment: Perhaps the documentation of [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will show you how you can extract those "hard" parts. Also, consider in the future that you'll get (better) answers if you show some form of code that you've tried yourself. If you specifically write that getting the emailaddress is easy, then why haven't you copied the code you're using in your question? Check out [writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code to extract information

```
# _*_ coding:utf-8 _*_
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

def grabHref(url,localfile):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    html = unicode(html,'gb2312','ignore').encode('utf-8','ignore')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    myfile = open(localfile,'wb')
    for link in soup.select("div >            a[href^=http://www.karmaloop.com/kazbah/browse]"):
        for item in BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(link['href']).read()).select("div > a[href^=mailto]"):
            contactInfo = item.get_text()
            print link['href']
            print contactInfo

        myfile.write(link['href'])
        myfile.write('\r\n')
        myfile.write(contactInfo)
        myfile.write('\r\n')
    myfile.close()



def main():
    url = "http://www.karmaloop.com/brands"
    localfile = 'Contact.txt'
    grabHref(url,localfile)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

But I still can only get email address here, how can I get phone number and address? Thanks

Comment: I get if right now. But for the css selector, "div > a[href^=mailto]" may not exist. I want to continue if can't find "div > a[href^=mailto]", how should I do?

Comment: I write if BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(link['href']).read()).select("div > div[id^=kazbah-contact]") == False:
            continue, but it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an answer. You should either edit your original question to include the new information, or open a separate question.