# Beautiful Soup: Extract details from <p> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My HTML page looks as follows:

```
 data = <section class="otln" itemscope="" itemtype="http://microformats.org/wiki/hCard">
 <header>
 <h3 class="org">Website:</h3>
 </header>
 <p><a href="http://www.abilityone.gov">U.S. AbilityOne Commission </a></p> </section>,
 <section class="otln" itemscope="" itemtype="http://microformats.org/wiki/hCard">
 <header>
 <h3 itemprop="name">Main Address:</h3>
 </header>
 <p class="spk street-address">1401 S. Clark Street<br/>Suite 715<br/><span class="locality">Arlington</span>, <span class="region">VA</span> <span class="postal-code">22202-3259</span></p> </section>,
 <section class="otln" itemscope="" itemtype="http://microformats.org/wiki/hCard">
 <header>
 <h3 itemprop="name">Phone Number:</h3>
 </header>
 <p>1-703-603-7740</p> </section>,
 <section class="otln" itemscope="" itemtype="http://microformats.org/wiki/hCard">
 <header>
 <h3 class="org">Government branch:</h3>
 </header>
 <p>Executive Department Sub-Office/Agency/Bureau</p>
 </section>
```

I want to extract all the details from the `<p>` tags of this HTML page like `href` of Website, Main Address, Phone Number and Government Branch. I have tried a lot of different variations to get them but not quite able to do it.

**EDITED**

My Code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
 website.append([l.find('a')['href'] for l in soup.find_all('section',class_='otln')])
```

The above attempt to get the 'href' throws `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`
I have the working solution to get Main address, Phone Number, and Government Branch. It would better if I could just get the 'href' of Website i.e. "http://www.ability.gov"

Comment: Show what you have tried...

Comment: Show your code and try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717853/finding-all-tags-and-attributes-in-a-html

Comment: The solution in the link provided will give me all the hrefs that are with the anchor tag but I want only specific href show in the edited version.

Comment: Are you aware that this is in a 'microdata' format rather than HTML?

Answer (score 2):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
for h, p in zip(soup.findAll('h3'), soup.findAll('p')):
    # h is the header, p is the paragraph
    a = p.find('a') # is it the website ?
    print('%-20s\t%s' % (h.text, a['href'] if bool(a) else p.text))
```