# How can I find the "follow up" to a re.findall() search?

Tags: html, regex, python-2.7

In this case I want to create a script that will find the prices off of the steam marketplace for a certain item.

```
import urllib2
import re
urllib2.Request("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dual%20Berettas%20%7C%20Dualing%20Dragons%20%28Battle-Scarred%29")
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
re.findall('class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee"',the_page)
```

So this gives me a list with all of the times that the string is repeated in the html.
the follow up (which I am looking for in the html file) is:

```
                    0,10€
```

How can I obtain these prices from the html file?

Comment: care to elaborate on that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python

Comment: So when you use the findall, what strings populate? how many? and what does the one you are looking for look like?