# How to validate HTML response returned by the API?

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, web-api-testing

In the API testing using Flask, I have some APIs which returns the HTML in the response.
While API testing I check only status code '200' in the response.
But from now I also want to validate data returned by the API.
Is it possible to validate HTML returned by the API

I am using python unittest to automate API testing.

Comment: show the existing code, you can add test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can validate your response.

If you get it in HTML just parse it and check what you need.

A very good example of how to parse HTML is here [Parsing HTML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python).

What you need to do is to import a class `BeautifulSoup` like this " `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`" and use it how is's shown in the examples in the link above.