# Extracting the title of my html line

Tags: python, regex

I have a question on extracting the title of an html line.

Let's say my line is:

```
<span class="title_name"> <a href="/?id=2124">Fairwood</a></span>
```

and lol, i had to add some extra spaces for the line to not show as a hyperlink..

How would I go about to automatically extract "Fairwood", given a number of lines that are formatted similarly, with different id's and titles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the downvotes? A small comment could be more helpful.

Comment: Searching for the string `href`, and then start capturing just after you encounter a `>` until you find a `<`

Comment: You might want to look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python and also please do not ever ever use regex to parse HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/190823

Comment: Perhaps the BeautifulSoup framework or alike could be of help:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring
Regex might work in simple cases, but it could be risky:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with a parser solution?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring('<span class="title_name"> <a href="/?id=2124">Fairwood</a></span>')
print(root.find("a").text)
# Fairwood
```

Answer (score 0):

If similarly format, then can try :

```
import re 
html='''
<span class="title_name1"> <a href="/?id=2124">Fairwood1</a></span>
<span class="title_name2"> <a href="/?id=2125">Fairwood2</a></span>'''
print re.findall(r'\w+(?=</a></span>)',html,re.M)
```

Comment: You don't need the multiline flag if there are no anchors to be matched.