# Regex to match html tag opening and closing tag and everthing between the tags (please check the image)

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, text-parsing

I want to match this kind of pattern and everything between the tags.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ML1T.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Q58.png]

Comment: In case you are attempting to process XMl or HTML via regexes please compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7733418

Comment: I have tried everything I need the solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Generally, we prefer you to post code (even example code) as text, not as a picture. Could you paste the original code (ensuring every line has a 4 space indent) to replace the picture?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick, usable, but (inevitably) imperfect solution, you can use `<li[^>]*>.*?<\/li>`. The ideal use case is low-use find-and-replace in a text file, not as any part of an actual HTML parser.

Also, you'll need to have singleline mode (sometimes called dot-all mode) enabled.

Edit:

I really don't know what's up with Python and newlines, but I was able to get [this](https://tio.run/##nVRRT9swEH4mv8LypKVFdcKgAgZJ@Al74HEdkpOY2JDY1vkCQ9t@e@ckDWpEW6Rasnx39nff@Xw@@4bS6Iv1WjXWABIQgdIOgaQkDMOkVkSVKb2@Or/0k5Ki5s6ltFUsR02GhanCaAaqkthZasUkd4wDmNdB37KibJt8xEnzIoDxUW3tIG@OFqbVo8NepllAPoykVC/TqJjSWsAA3AnZjULxG/cd7xCcSBCPKa2Vfo4kNvV2Mjqj55UCFFJScuTMH2aT1PVWXpZDuqyXlK5S@u0AacermmpCNKSQEgdFSv1m9GRFRUluoBSQ0jNKeI0p/cSrnfoshSsOIzqQLwujq6xQ@JbEG@UgS2yPiGJw/wlSLqdQKXiXzhEtl0cQf63wdpzEPw8I54KTfniMv68QePR1k5jvq8XYF@O@PWe53oq1Kx2yWYcfxuBdd5KX5tXfQ@fO3voX8tidX2Yf4XuNf7m@Olt@v6TZrqiTuFaZ7w2BBaVxFv5o0bZ4Q@iffzSMHg00HGcBiMi1@Qy6FvLzIft1ms3ubqK/Kz0/vUtWvYuF7zAL0nebhe870f18Pg/W6/8) working:

```
re.sub(r'<li[^>]*>(?:.|\n)*?<\/li>', '', instr)
```

To generalize to any number (if Python >= 3.6):

```
n = 8726872
re.sub(fr'<li id="{n}"[^>]*>(?:.|\n)*?<\/li>', '', instr)
```

And obligatory parsing HTML the better (safer and cleaner way) link:
[Parsing HTML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python)

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a fatal error and eschewed my usual practice of verifying my answers. Apologies, I've fixed it.

Comment: It is matching only 1 out of 75 patterns, I have added the exact code please try to accomodate the number matching pattern as well with opening line tag. 
 Please check this url for code https://pastebin.com/bY52ua07

Comment: Try checking the box labelled `. matches newline`. I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: If the id is important it can just be modified to: `<li id="8726872"[^>]*>.*?<\/li>`

Comment: unfortunately, it didnt.

Comment: Or in PCRE regex, the `s` (singleline) flag is necessary.

Comment: I am using python not PCRE wait i will try it on atom text editor

Comment: Next time, you should add Python as a tag in your question. That will make it easier for people to help you. I can give you a Python solution, but it will take a second.

Comment: please generalize the regex for any id means for any number