# How to get the text below <b> as values and text inside <b> as keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
<div>
    <b> "Key1" </b>
    " Value1 "
    <br>
    <b> "Key2" </b>
    " Value2 "
    <br>
    <b> "Key3" </b>
    " Value3 "
    <br>
```

Here i need the keys as keys in a dict 'A' and values as values of A[keys]

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a coding service.

Comment: I need to convert them to a dict like {'Key1' : 'Value1', 'Key2' : value2, 'Key3' : 'Value3'}  @Nordle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python)

Comment: @gehbiszumeis I cannot use the BeautifulSoup since i have my limitations but got the solution in another way, please see the answer section. Thank you

Comment: @arjun. I see. Glad to read, that you found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried another method and it is working.

1. added the 'Key1','Key2','Key3' to a list named dict_keys
2. added the 'Value1','Value2','Value3' to a list named dict_values
3. made a dict by using zip() function;

   ```
   data_dict = dict(zip(dict_keys,dict_values))
   ```

Now the data_dict is the required dictionary which contains the keys and values