# Get all substrings between two different start and ending delimiters

Tags: python, html, substring, string-matching

I am trying in Python 3 to get a list of all substrings of a given String a, which start after a delimiter x and end right before a delimiter y.
I have found solutions which only get me the first occurence, but the result needs to be a list of all occurences.

```
start = '>'
end = '</'
s = '<script>a=eval;b=alert;a(b(/XSS/.source));</script><script>a=eval;b=alert;a(b(/XSS/.source));</script>'"><marquee><h1>XSS by Xylitol</h1></marquee>'
print((s.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])
```

the above example is what I've got so far. But I am searching for a more elegant and stable way to get all the occurences.

So the expected return as list would contain the javascript code as following entries:

```
a=eval;b=alert;a(b(/XSS/.source));
```

```
a=eval;b=alert;a(b(/XSS/.source));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing HTML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python)

Comment: Sadly not... I am actually working with Beautiful Soup and Esprima. The input strings on the other hand dont necessary contain a full HTML Structure that could be parsed. They will rather be URL's which contain XSS Paylods and therefor can contain Javascript. I need to manually extract all <script> </script> tags out of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for patterns in strings seems like a decent job for regular expressions.
This should return a list of anything between a pair of `<script>` and `</script>`:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'<script>(.*?)</script>')
s = '<script>a=eval;b=alert;a(b(/XSS/.source));</script><script>a=eval;b=alert;a(b(/XSS/.source));</script>\'"><marquee><h1>XSS by Xylitol</h1></marquee>'
print(pattern.findall(s))
```

Result:

```
['a=eval;b=alert;a(b(/XSS/.source));', 'a=eval;b=alert;a(b(/XSS/.source));']
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I was hoping for!