# How to parse a paragraph regardless of applied styles in html using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to create a Python function (that uses regular expressions) replace every paragraph of HTML which contains '$$' with the letter '1'. I need to apply the same even there are some styles exists in paragraph,

```
s = "<p>adsadfsaaadsadsaExample String</p><p>$$</p>"
replaced = re.sub('<p>\$\$</p>', '1',s)
print (replaced)
```

Expected Input:

```
<p>i have</p> <p style="text-align:justify">$$</p>
<p> asdas jas dafad</p>
<p>$$<p>
<p>asdasd</p>
<p><span>$$</span></p>
```

Expected Output:

```
<p>i have</p> 1 
<p> asdas jas dafad</p>
1
<p>asdasd</p>
1
```

please help

Comment: don't do it! use html.parser instead. if you still insist, read https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing HTML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

pattern = r'\<p.*?\>.*?\<\/p\>'
html_str = '<p>i have</p> <p style="text-align:justify">$$</p><p> asdas jas dafad</p><p>$$</p><p>asdasd</p><p><span>$$</span></p>'
new_html_str = re.sub(pattern, lambda match: "1" if '$$' in match.group() else match.group(),s)
print(new_html_str)

prints - '<p>i have</p> 1<p> asdas jas dafad</p>1<p>asdasd</p>1'
```

my answer is completely based on your approach, for a better solution, I suggest to parse the html and process.

Comment: Thanks bro, This is just a potion of the code, My intention is not to parse entire code, Just add some extra tags and process, so I followd this approch

Comment: Don't parse HTML using regex, this breaks for example with comments in HTML that might have `<p>` or `</p>` in them.

Answer (score -2):

```
import re

s = """<p>i have</p> <p style="text-align:justify">$$</p> 
<p> asdas jas dafad</p> 
<p>$$<p> 
<p>asdasd</p> 
<p><span>$$</span></p>"""

result = re.sub(r"<p .*=.*>\$\$.*?</?p>", "1", s)
result = re.sub(r"<p.*>\$\$.*?</?p>", "1", result) 

print(result)
```

Output:

```
<p>i have</p> 1
<p> asdas jas dafad</p>
1
<p>asdasd</p>
1
```