# extract data from html tag with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```html
<div class="media-body text-right">

  <h4 style="color:#fff;font-weight:bold"> 790.00</h4>
  <span style="color:white;font-weight:bold">Current Balance (Earn)</span>

 </div>
```

I want to get the value "790.00" from this html code and put it in a variable. How can i do this with python? please HELP.

Comment: `x = '790.00 Current Balance (Earn)' value = x.split(' ')[0]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing HTML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python)

Comment: What did you try after `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` already, any [example] to show? A simple [`soup.get_text()`](https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/#use-a-beautifulsoup-object) serves as start ️

Comment: If you want to select only this ```<div>``` from the entire HTML, you need to either share the URL or the complete HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="media-body text-right">

  <h4 style="color:#fff;font-weight:bold"> 790.00</h4>
  <span style="color:white;font-weight:bold">Current Balance (Earn)</span>

 </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
val = soup.find("h4").get_text(strip=True)
print(val)
```

Prints:

```
790.00
```

Comment: Sir, how can i extract the particular part of the html code from the whole html source code. Actually, i need the value "790" only.

Comment: @AbidChowdhury Can you share the URL? To convert string `790.00` to `790` you can do `val = val.split(".")[0]`

Comment: Sir , you didn't get me actually. I want to extract the following code from the whole webpage.       <div class="media-body text-right">

  <h4 style="color:#fff;font-weight:bold"> 790.00</h4>
  <span style="color:white;font-weight:bold">Current Balance (Earn)</span>

 </div>