# Replace all HTML tags except some using Regex in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to replace all HTML tags with two exceptions using regex and Python.

Right now this is the regex I'm using: `<\/?(?!(?:em|strong)\b)[a-z](?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*>`
And this is an example text I'm trying to "sanitize":

```html
<p><em>test text</em></p>
<p><strong>test test test</strong></p>
<div>some other text</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>
```

and the output is the following:

```
test text
test test test
some other text
```

even though it should be:

```
<em>test text</em>
<strong>test test test</strong>
some other text
```

The code I used to test everything is:

```py
import re

text = '''<p><em>test text</em></p>
<p><strong>test test test</strong></p>
<div>some other text</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>'''

res = re.sub("<\/?(?!(?:em|strong)\b)[a-z](?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*>", '', text)

print(res.strip())
```

Right now I believe regex is the go-to because the text I have to sanitize comes from an API, so it's not gonna scale in any way.

Got any suggestion? Why does it replace the "em" and "strong" tags even with the negative lookahead?

Comment: A ripple in the force is felt ...

Comment: Aside from your specific issue, regex isn't really appropriate for html (html isn't a regular language). Maybe a parser would be better...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python

Comment: If you're just trying to get rid of all tags other than `em` and `strong` why bother with all the balancing/nesting logic? Just use something like `<\/?(?!em|strong)\w+>` and replace it with "".

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie A parser won't work if the HTML input isn't well formed. It looks like OP just wants to do a simple string replacement, so this shouldn't be outside of basic regex capability.

Comment: You make a reasonable point @CAustin, but it's not true about parsers and malformed html. The `html5lib` parser, for instance, will parse html in the same way a browser does, and can handle malformed input.

Comment: You can prepend the pattern with `r` for raw string like `res = re.sub(r"</?(?!(?:em|strong)\b)[a-z](?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*>", '', text)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird that was the solution, thank you! If you send it as answer I'll accept it