# How to remove extra text from variable? [PYTHON]

Tags: python, parsing

I make a parser from one site where authorization is used, and in the end I get a generalized block with the necessary information and html-trash. How to leave only texts like `INEEDTHISTEXT`?

What i have now:

```html
[<div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
</div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
                <div class="dnevnik-lesson__attach">
<a class="button button--outline button--purple" href="example.link"><i class="fal fa-fw fa-file-powerpoint"></i><span class="button__title">example.pptx</span></a>
</div>
</div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT 
 
 
                <div class="dnevnik-lesson__attach">
<a class="button button--outline button--purple" href="линкf"><i class="fal fa-fw fa-file-pdf"></i><span class="button__title">тесты Чеботарева-113-114.pdf</span></a>
</div>
</div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>, <div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
 
 
 
            </div>]
```

What i need:

`INEEDTHISTEXT INEEDTHISTEXT`

and etc.

I tried replace(), [cut:] but it didn't work.

Comment: Parse your input as HTML, then go and find the text you need in the structured document. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HTML parser such as [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), but here is a simple regex that should work for this case. It may not work with all web pages:

```py
import re

html = """[<div class="dnevnik-lesson__task">
<i class="dnevnik-lesson-icon"></i>INEEDTHISTEXT
...
"""

print(re.findall(r">([\w]+)\s+<", html))
```

This will print

```
['INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT',
 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT',
 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT',
 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT',
 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT',
 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT',
 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT',
 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT', 'INEEDTHISTEXT']
```

Comment: That regex isn't specific at all and is likely to find a ton of text on the page.

Comment: Yes, and that seems to be the aim of the OP: _"How to leave only texts?"_

Comment: My point is that you aren't specifying any tags at all, only text inside tags... that's very likely going to find a lot of text on the page, much of it not the desired text.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Selenium script that grabs that text and strips off the whitespace.

```
lessons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dnevnik-lesson__task")
for lesson in lessons:
    print(lesson.text.strip())
```